# div margin level why when we apply margin property to lower div it apply on the upper div

Tags: html, css

Here i have three divs i want the div three to have margin from the top but since then I am giving it the margin to the third div but what and expected to  move from the top only bit the complete div is moving

```css
*{  
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.divone{
  background-color:red;
}
.divtwo{
  margin:10px 4px;
}
.divthree{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="divone">
  <div class="divtwo">
    <div class="divthree">
      <div class="ndiv">
        <h3>I am</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="ndiv">
        <h3>Hello</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's regular behaviour. Google "collapsing margins" for a description of this phenomenon. Or just read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you're currently applying it to `.divtwo`.

What you actually need to do is apply `padding` to `.divthree` to get what you want.

Change your CSS to the following to accomplished that:

```
*{  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.divone{
  background-color: red;
}

.divthree{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 4px;
}
```